# TypeError: .val is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, where I am selecting all matching elements that start with the same name, excluding one I do not want included in the group.

```
var myInputBoxes= $('input[id ^= "SubjectText"]').not('#SubjectTextNew');
for (i = 0 ; i < myInputBoxes.length; i++){
    var SubjectId = myInputBoxes[i].id.replace('SubjectText', '');
    var Subject = myInputBoxes[i].val();
}
```

This gives me the following error in firefox

> TypeError: myInputBoxes[i].val is not a function

Why would it fail on the val function?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Accessing a jQuery object using bracket notation returns a DOMElement which does not have the `val()` function. If you want to retrieve an element by its index within a matched set you need to use `eq()`:

```
var Subject = myInputBoxes.eq(i).val();
```

Alternatively you can retain the DOMElement and use the `value` property:

```
var Subject = myInputBoxes[i].value;
```

Comment: Also you can convert `DOMElement` to `jQuery` object like so `$(subjectBoxes[i]).val();`

Comment: While that would work, what's the point of taking a jQuery object, getting a DOMElement from it, then converting that back to a jQuery object?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I change my query to return jQuery objects? (and be able to query on only a partial id?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You appear to already be doing that?

Comment: I am indeed, but the result in returning DomElements. Can I do that and return jQuery objects?

Comment: Could you explain the difference between my code and the example on the jquery website. They appear to be using the square bracket notation and returning a jquery object https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: In that example they're using the square brackets in the selector string, not on a JS object, hence the difference.

Comment: got it, I had totally misunderstood what was going on. It's the array that's the problem, not the selector string.

Answer (score 1):

Because `subjectBoxes[i]` is not a jQuery object, if it is a jQuery object then you can use .eq() to get a jQuery wrapper reference to the element at the passed index

```
var myInputBoxes = $('input[id ^= "SubjectText"]').not('#SubjectTextNew');
myInputBoxes.each(function (e, el) {
    var SubjectId = this.id.replace('SubjectText', '');
    var Subject = subjectBoxes.eq(i).val();
})
```